# SQL Table Design For Efficient SELECT

Tags: php, sql, database-design

Generic table setup to explain my structure - reduced to specify the core of my goals. Based after recipes.

tbl_item

item_id, item_name, misc_info
1, bread, etc.
2, cupcake, etc.

tbl_ingredients_item

ii_id, ing_id, item_id
1, 1, 1
2, 1, 3
3, 2, 1
4, 2, 4

tbl_ingredients
ing_id, ing_name
1, Flour
2, Salt
3, Butter
4, Frosting

---

I need to select every row of tbl_items, and its ingredients. Then in php, iterate through each row so I can spit out the resulting statement:

Item: bread
Misc Info: Etc.
Ingredients:
1. Flour
2. Salt

As it stands I believe the array will end up like this:

bread, etc., flour
bread, etc., salt
cupcake, etc., flour
cupcake, etc., frosting

Is this the proper table setup, and what is an efficient way of dealing with this in php?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the database structure simple and intuitive. What you've got is fine.

If you want to read out the recipes in one DB call, your options are to write a SQL query that joins your 3 tables, or write a view over your query and select from that. If that isn't fast enough (and your DB supports it), you can create your view and index it, so that the denormalised data is persisted on disk (thus avoiding the joins).

Comment: To counteract the duplicate rows returned - instead of a php loop to massage the array - the SQL command GROUP_CONCAT helped greatly.